# Getting warnings and errors after enabling proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I enabled proguard for my release build and when I ran the project, I get [these warnings and errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13471683/). Here is my `buildTypes` block:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

The build message was too long to post here so have put external link.
What is the reason for these warnings? Is there something I have done wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any external library that you are using you need to add rules in your proguard.pro file.

For example in my project these are the proguard rules I added for retrofit and okhttp

```
# Retrofit 1.X

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
```

These rules are taken from

https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit.pro

So you need to check similarly for each library what are the rules to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Each library mentioned in the warnings has its' own proguard rules which you have to put in your proguard-rules.pro. For example you can find ButterKnife's rules at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ "Proguard" section.